# Postgis Postgres client integration not working?

Tags: database, postgresql, gis, postgis

I'm experimenting with Postgis.  I have setup a database added a table with a geometry column with points in it and indexed that column.

One thing I find strange is that in many cases the data in the columns is not translated for display in the client.

For example, if I paste this into the shell

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(75.15 29.53 1,77 29 1,77.6 29.5 1, 75.15 29.53 1)'));
```

I get this result

```
    st_makepolygon                                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 010300008001000000040000009A99999999C9524048E17A14AE873D40000000000000F03F00000000004053400000000000003D40000000000000F03F66666666666653400000000000803D40000000000000F03F9A99999999C9524048E17A14AE873D40000000000000F03F
(1 row)
```

Shouldn't I get something like this?

```
st_asewkt
-----------
POLYGON((75.15 29.53 1,77 29 1,77.6 29.5 1,75.15 29.53 1))
```

Also when I select points out of my geometry column I see the raw data for them as well.

If this is correct how do I translate the data so I can see what is in the geometry easily?

I would like to be able to see my points in the column display as POINT(x,y,z) or something similar.

It is interesting that if I run something like this operation

```
SELECT ST_Extent(geom) FROM towns WHERE town = 'BOSTON';
```

The client shows me this result

```
    st_extent     
------------------
 BOX(10 10,10 10)
(1 row)
```

Comment: OK now I see that if I wrap that hex result in ST_asewkt() I get a decoded result.  Is there any way to have this be the default display for geometry columns?

Answer (score 2):

Geometries are stored in the database as [well-known binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_binary) objects, since it is a compact and lossless format. When querying this data type, it is decoded into a hexadecimal text representation, as shown in your question. The only hack to change the default output behavior that I can think of is to redefine the cast.

This hack requires PostGIS to be installed from the `postgis.sql` enabler script, and not the `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` method. And then, redefine the cast from `geometry` to `text`:

```
DROP CAST (geometry AS text);
CREATE CAST (geometry AS text) WITH FUNCTION ST_AsText(geometry) AS IMPLICIT;
```

Which now shows the following behavior:

```
SELECT '010300008001000000040000009A99999999C9524048E17A14AE87'
'3D40000000000000F03F00000000004053400000000000003D40000000000'
'000F03F66666666666653400000000000803D40000000000000F03F9A9999'
'9999C9524048E17A14AE873D40000000000000F03F'::geometry::text;

                             text
---------------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON Z ((75.15 29.53 1,77 29 1,77.6 29.5 1,75.15 29.53 1))
(1 row)
```

but it only works with `::text` casts. Without it, it casts `geometry` to `bytea`, which has a default cast to text as hex format.

I don't recommend this hack, however. Just remember to use ST_AsText in your SQL statements if you need a human readable WKT string. Also, keep in mind that WKT is one of several text formats; see ["Geometry Outputs" in the manual](http://www.postgis.org/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs) for others.

Comment: you know how can set the geometry output in case of migration ? i have a geometry col but table export (aws dms) gime me a kml (wtf)

Comment: im forget, how can see te actual rule for geometry cast en db ?